# "SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh - After destroying Enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a NevMeshSurface with Enemies. All Enemies have a NevMeshAgent.

When the Player dies, all Enemies should get destroyed:

```
GameObject[] enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
foreach (GameObject enemy in enemies)
{
    Destroy(enemy.gameObject);
}
```

When this happens, i get the error:

> "SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been
>   placed on a NavMesh.

This is the Enemy Script:

```
public GameObject player;
NavMeshAgent agent;

void Start()
{
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    agent.Warp(transform.position);
}

void Update()
{
    if (player.gameObject != null && gameObject.activeSelf)
    {
        agent.SetDestination(player.transform.position);
    }   
}
```

The NevMeshSurface is baked when the Enemies are spawned.

And it works great, until the player dies, then the error appears and i don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Do you have a bool or anything for tracking if a player is alive or not?

Comment: @JoshAdams No, when the player dies he gets teleported to the last tent he visited.

Comment: Have you tried just checking if the player object is null instead of player.gameObject? Also, is the player object Destroyed when killed or just simply moved?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Agent is destroyed but Update() is still getting called. Looking at the rest of your code, this doesn't seem too likely (unless there's something weird in the code you haven't posted). I would modify the Update method to debug what's actually wrong:

```
void Update()
{
    if (player.gameObject != null && gameObject.activeSelf)
    {
        print("Is agent null: " + (agent == null));
        agent.SetDestination(player.transform.position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution today:

I changed the position from the player 0.5 seconds after i destroyed the enemys, and now it works fine!